# Middle mouse button doesn't always rotate view

Tags: 3d-view

I am having a problem with the most basic possible thing: the middle mouse button will only rotate the view sometimes.  If I left-click somewhere (on or off an object), sometimes it stops working.  My mouse is a Microsoft 5-button, with tilt wheel.

I am a completely novice Blender user.  Clean install, factory settings, mouse works in every other application.

I left-click in the 3D view, which moves the red-and-white reticle/crosshairs. Then I try to use the middle mouse button to rotate the view.  Sometimes it works, but sometimes nothing happens (though the scroll wheel always zooms reliably.)  If I keep clicking and re-clicking the middle mouse button, eventually Blender will decide to rotate the view, but it's not a certainty.

Once it permits the view to rotate, the situation is stable until I left-click somewhere again. Where in the view I click (for both left and middle buttons) seems to have no effect on the problem.

Because the problem seems to appear completely at random and is so transient, it looks to me like a bug.  If it's not, I have no idea how to tell it from normal Blender behavior.  I've tried using Emulate Three Button Mouse, but the problem seems to occur for alt-left mouse button as well, so I know it's not my middle mouse button.

Comment: Have you tried another mouse?

Comment: It might not be your MMB... but it may be your LMB. It seems like the issues you're having are all relative to when you click with the LMB.

Comment: I was using a Microsoft mouse at one point and had the same problem. The issue (for me at least) was the mouse itself. Try testing Blender with a different mouse or enable 'Emulate 3 button mouse' in the settings and use Alt-Leftclick to rotate the view.

Comment: @CharlesL OP already tried *Emulate 3 button mouse*, "I've tried using Emulate Three Button Mouse, but the problem seems to occur for alt-left mouse button as well". BTW, I too have a 5 button microsoft mouse, but no problems here..

Comment: I haven't tried another mouse; I don't have another one that works easily accessible at this point.  The mouse I have is new.  I know it's not the LMB - the reticle/crosshair moves wherever I like, and I've found the problem occurs on startup, without any left-click (other than to dismiss the splash screen.)  I will test with a different mouse when I get the chance.

Comment: @DevinCarless Does your MMB behave oddly with other applications too or just blender?

Comment: I almost never use my MMB - it requires a lot of effort to depress it.  But in Chrome it turns the cursor-arrow to a four-way-directional circle reliably.

Comment: Is it really bad lag then?

Comment: It may have been lag.  But I've found what seems to be a reliable workaround: I switched to LMB select and 'Emulate Three Button Mouse' (even though it's greyed out.)  Now alt-LMB pans the view.  I'm finding Blender 2.68 a lot easier to  work with than the last time I tried it; thank you for all the prompt replies!